# if statement in foreach loop using last true value when false

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array being looped with an if-else statement in it. The condition is if the name starts with a dot put the string in `$gridNames` else put the string in `$cssNames`. Somehow the last name that was valid for `$gridNames` is being used for the rest of the loop although the condotion being false.

Here's the `$selector["name"]` array:

```
string(4) ".row"
string(10) ".inner_row"
string(7) ".column"
string(13) ".inner_column"
string(12) "hey im a div"
string(8) "column 1"
string(5) "row 2"
```

And the code itself:

```
foreach ($element_css["element_css"] as $selector) {
  $name = $selector["name"];
  $lenght = strlen($name);
  $firstLetter = substr($name, 0, -($lenght - 1));
  if ($firstLetter == ".") {
      $gridName = substr($name, 1, $lenght);
  } else {
      $nameByWords = explode(" ", $name);
      foreach ($nameByWords as $word) {
        $allWords .= $word;
      }
      $cssName = $allWords;
      $allWords = "";
  }
  var_dump($gridName);
}
```

The `var_dump` gives me:

```
string(3) "row"
string(9) "inner_row"
string(6) "column"
string(12) "inner_column"
string(12) "inner_column"
string(12) "inner_column"
string(12) "inner_column"
```

The result I want is:

```
string(3) "row"
string(9) "inner_row"
string(6) "column"
string(12) "inner_column"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_dump($grid_name)` will execute in every iteration of loop because this is written outside of if-else condition so for the last 3 strings, `$grid_name` wouldn't change but that `var_dump()` will execute so the last value of `$grid_name` would be used to display.

Answer (score 0):

You never set `$gridName` to anything else, so what do you expect? You could set it to `NULL` or `""` depending on what exactly you want, either at the beginning of the loop or inside the `else` clause. The latter is a little more efficient.